# Charles Proxy SSL Certificate not working on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ssl, charles-proxy

Possible duplicate of [Charles Proxy SSL Certificate not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41228511/513413) but I provide more details since those answers didn't help me.

I am on my MacBook (High Sierra 10.13.6) and I want to see what my web app is sending/receving over Chrome browser, Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit). I am using Charles V3.12.3 (old but I don't have license for the most recent one).

According to [their doc for Mac OS](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/):

> In Charles go to the Help menu and choose "SSL Proxying > Install
>   Charles Root Certificate". Keychain Access will open. Find the
>   "Charles Proxy..." entry, and double-click to get info on it. Expand
>   the "Trust" section, and beside "When using this certificate" change
>   it from "Use System Defaults" to "Always Trust". Then close the
>   certificate info window, and you will be prompted for your
>   Administrator password to update the system trust settings.

It's trusted in my Keychain as you see here:

[image]

However, I still get a lot of `<unknown>` things! in Charles:

[image]

Any idea what I am missing?

- I have restarted Chrome browser as well as Charles few times. I even restarted my system once however I am still getting same `<unknown>` responses.
- I'm able to see my request/responses on Chrome DevTools without any problem.
- My VPN is off. In fact I deleted the whole app (as several people complained about having it on).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Charles will (thankfully) not automatically perform man in the middle attacks on all your SSL connections.

You need to enable SSL proxying on a per domain basis. Either by context clicking the connection and choosing `Enable SSL Proxying` from the menu or in the `SSL Proxying Settings` window in the `Tools` menubar.

[image: enable SSL proxying]

Comment: Oh man, I spent around 5 hours on this. Aren't they supposed to put it in their doc, wtf. Anyways, thanks for your answer. I confirm I am able to see Requests/Responses after doing your change. Thanks. [I'll accept your answer in next 4 min]

Answer (score 0):

Try restart your browser.

I have the same issue, certificate is trust, but content still unknow.

After quit and restart Chrome browser. Everything works.