# "Charles Proxy CA (2 Mar 2019, 2H1-XX-XXXXX.local)" certificate is not trusted

Tags: ssl, charles-proxy

I'm trying to install Charles Root Certificate on my MacBook Pro version 10.14.1 so that I can see https packets in my Chrome browser.

So I did what the [official document](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/) says: `Help Menu` -> `SSL Proxying` -> `Install Charles Root Certificate`. Then the certificate shows up at the System tab of Keychains in *Keychain Access* app.

But when I click on the certificate, it says `"Charles Proxy CA (2 Mar 2019, 2H1-XX-XXXXX.local)" certificate is not trusted`. What might cause this problem? How can I let my system to trust the certificate?

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228511/charles-proxy-ssl-certificate-not-working/42212184) says that I can see a prompt asking me if I want to trust the certificate. But I can't find the prompt.

My Charles web debugging proxy version is trial v 4.2.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that you can double click on the un-trusted certificate, expand its *Trust* section, then select *Always Trust* option. This can solve the problem I mentioned in the original question.

[image]

Comment: Why you say "this can solve" and not "this solves"? Is actually depending on any other setting or something we may be missing. If it entirelly solves your problem, could you please change it to "this solved my problem", or something like this? Thx!

Comment: @LluísSuñol, English is not my mother language. I'll appreciate it if you could tell me the difference between "this can solve" and not "this solves".

Comment: From my perspective, using "can" makes me think that the proposed solution may solve the problem in some circumstances, but also that it may not solve it in some other circumstances. When I read "this solved my problem" I clearly understand that you got your problem solved by applying only your proposed solution, not depending consciously in any other factor. In any case, my mother language is neither english, so don't rely 100% on my words! :)