# How to resolve the Unkown Path on Charles over VPN

Tags: charles-proxy

Charles can catch the data from the web, eg domain.com, but I can't see the path. How can I config for displaying the path?

[image: charles with unkown]

Update:

Thanks to @shaochuancs, but after I enable the SSL config, the other problem comes.

It says

> Charles failed to connect to the remote host. Check that your Internet connection is ok and that the remote host is accessible. Maybe your network uses a proxy server to access the Internet? You can configure Charles to use an external proxy server in the External Proxy Settings.

[image: charles with SSL but failed]

Answer (score 1):

The path is "unknown" because the target website is using SSL. Please note there is a "Notes" in the screenshot: "SSL Proxying not enabled for this host...". It has nothing to do with VPN.

To enable SSL Proxying, you can open `Proxy - SSL Proxying Settings` panel, and add the target host there:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1**

Follow the appropriate instructions:

(NOTE: There is also an option in Charles help for IOS Simulator cert very similar to the osx option.)

**Windows / Internet Explorer**

In Charles go to the Help menu and choose "SSL Proxying > Install Charles Root Certificate". A window will appear warning you that the CA Root certificate is not trusted. Click the "Install Certificate" button to launch the Certificate Import Wizard. The certificate must be imported into the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" certificate store, so override the automatic certificate store selection. Complete the wizard and your Charles Root Certificate is now installed. You may need to restart IE before the installation takes affect.

**Mozilla Firefox**

After installing the Charles Add-on for Mozilla, go to the Tools menu, the Charles submenu, and choose the "Install Charles Root Certificate" option. You will be presented with a certificate import dialog. Tick the option "Trust this CA to identify websites" and complete the import.

**Mac OS X**

In Charles go to the Help menu and choose "SSL Proxying > Install Charles Root Certificate". Keychain Access will open, and prompt you about the certificate. Click the "Always Trust" button. You will then be prompted for your Administrator password to update the system trust settings. You may need to quit and reopen Safari to see the change.

Reference here:
[Charles Proxy SSL Certificate not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228511/charles-proxy-ssl-certificate-not-working#42212184)

**STEP 2**

You may need to activate the certificate on ios simulators or osx.

OSX Reference:
[Charles Proxy SSL Certificate not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228511/charles-proxy-ssl-certificate-not-working#48891484)

IOS Reference:
[Charles Proxy SSL Certificate not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228511/charles-proxy-ssl-certificate-not-working#55047194)